# I want to display an image when button is clicked and at same time the color of text in button should change. I am using bootstrap for this

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is my page. When I click on view button an image should display and text color should change.
I I take  tag with  image is coming beside button. Any body please give me solution.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload some code and CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you would provide your code but maybe this will help you:

```
<button id="myButton" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<div id="someDiv">
</div>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = "path/to/your/image.jpg";
        document.getElementById("someDiv").appendChild(img);
        document.getElementById("myButton").style.color = "blue";
    }
</script>
```